# QGIS relation_aggregate, how does this work?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I've been trying to use this feature but I'm not being able to make it work. I'm using this syntax:

`relation_aggregate(relation := 'tubo_et_face_et_inicial', aggregate := 'sum', expression := "lenght_linear")`

to try to sum up all the values in the "lenght_linear field of the child table, to a virtual field in the parent table. Is this syntax correct, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try to write without tags:
('Tubo_et_face_et_inicial', 'Sum', "lenght_linear")
it works?

tags you can not use them if you respect the order.

Comment: Documentation is here but no more precions: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/59

Comment: @user88753 expression:= "column_label"_ must be in the child table. Maybe save your project , close and reopen. Tested and works on 2.18.3

Answer (score 2):

In <= 2.18.6, after you added a new relation in project properties:

1. Save the project.
2. Restart QGIS
3. try again the field calculator with your formula.

It's what i have to do to make it working.